# How to write the a new select query with backward compatibility after adding a new column to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I have a MySQL table running for 4 months and I have a select statement in that table, like below.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time)),
        '-',
        IF(
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time)) < 10,
            CONCAT('0', MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time))),
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time))
        )
    ) AS Period,
    (
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN system_name = 'System' THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END)

    ) AS "Some data",
FROM table_name
GROUP BY
    Period
ORDER BY
    Period DESC
```

Lately, I've added a new feature and a column, let's say `is_rerun`. This value is just added and not exist previously. Now, i would like to write a query with the current statement which checks the `system_name` and also the `is_rerun` field and if this field exists and value is 1 then return 1 and if the column not exist or it its value is zero, then return null.

I tried `IF EXISTS re_run THEN 1 ELSE NULL`, but no luck. I can also insert values for the previous runs but i don't want to do that. Is there any solution. Thanks.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time)),
        '-',
        IF(
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time)) < 10,
            CONCAT('0', MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time))),
            MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_time))
        )
    ) AS Period,
    (
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN system_name = 'System' AND IF EXISTS is_rerun THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END)

    ) AS "Some data",
FROM table_name
GROUP BY
    Period
ORDER BY
    Period DESC
```

Comment: What default value did you use for your new column? After adding this new column it does exist for all rows, not just for new rows.

Comment: How can you have or have not a column? If you have added a column it could have a null value.

Comment: _Important Info_ The new Column WILL exists on ALL ROWS, New and Old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: you have a `group by` query, so you need to put `is_rerun` in an aggregate function.

Based on your description, I think that something like `case(case when is_rerun = 1 then 1 end)` should do the work: it returns `1` if any `is_rerun` in the group is `1`, else `null`.

Or if you can live with `0` instead of `null`, then you can use a simpler expression: `max(is_rerun = 1)`.

Note that your query could be largely simplified as for the date formating logic and the conditional count. I would phrase it as:

```
select
    date_format(from_unixtime(creation_time),'%Y-%m') period,
    sum(system_name = 'System') some_data,
    max(is_rerun = 1) is_rerun
from mytable
group by period
order by period desc
```

Comment: Your query has three fields, the original query just has two fields, that's why this cannot be a simplified version of the original.

Comment: The `date_format` worked thanks, but i am not sure about the max method. I would like to find the data where `system_name` is 'System' and `is_rerun` is equal to 1 at the same time.

Comment: @M.OguzOzcan: `sum(sytem_name = 'System')`, this is equivalent to the `count(case ...)` of your original query, just shorter to write. As for `is_rerun`, I explained what the expression does. So you want a *conditional* max, that only takes in account rows where `name = 'System')`? If so, you can use `max(is_rerun = 1 and system_name = 'System')`.